# Books / Articles on how mathematical education has changed over time

Tags: math-history

Can anyone recommend books/articles on approaches to teaching mathematics over centuries? How has it been changing since the beginning of mathematical education?

Thank you

Comment: http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/, in open beta, might be a good place for this, ideally if you can expand on what exactly you're looking for since this is a broad and deep area.

Comment: Thank you for pointing in that direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with :

- Ronald Calinger (editor), [Vita Mathematica : Historical Research and Integration with Teaching](https://books.google.it/books?id=D21wKHoYGg0C&pg=PA1) (1996), at least for some papers.

Answer (score 2):

[The International Journal for the History of Mathematics Education](http://www.comap.com/historyjournal/archives.htm) is devoted to this question. The first issue is available [online](http://www.comap.com/historyjournal/pdf/Vol1No1.pdf), but for the other issues you need a subscription (or access to a library with one).